# var v1 = new class(params) , object = {}

Tags: node.js, multipart

Hi I don't know what exactly do this kind of sentences:

```
var v1 = new class(params) , object = {}
```

The real example was: (From https://github.com/visionmedia/parted Usage paragraph)

```
var parser = new multipart(type, options) , parts = {};
```

I understand that parser will be a new multipart object, but parts?! what exactly do? Create empty object? where I have to push some data?

Thank's in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var declarations can take multiple variables. Example:

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
```

That declares two variables, a and b, and assigns them the values 1 and 2, respectively.

In other words, in your example, parts is a new variable that is assigned an "empty" object.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` in javascript creates a new empty object using JavaScript's literal object notation.

Other examples of creating objects using the literal object notation:

```js
obj1 = { foo: 2 } // Now obj1.foo is 2
obj2 = { foo: 3, bar: "hello" } // Now obj2.foo is 3 and obj2.bar is "hello"
```